# How to tell if a process is an application?

Tags: c++, windows

So I take a snapshot and view processes like [this.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686701%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) Works great except I want to weed out all the trivial processes and only get a list of applications like the windows task manager does. How would I do this?

Comment: Depends on your definition what an 'application' might be (e.g. a process with a main window, etc.) ...

Comment: I don't know what the difference is which is why I asked the question. It may be processes which have windows but I have no idea. I think it should be pretty obvious what I'm talking about if you open windows task manager and see how it separates background processes and applications. That is why I said "applications."

Comment: I think that separation refers to processes with a main window and such without. IFAIR it's possible to get that information along with a process ID, but don't ask me how to do this in detail.

Comment: Use EnumWindows to enumerate all the toplevel windows that the user can see.  GetWindowThreadProcessId() gets you the owner process.

Comment: Yeah, I had figured that out shortly before you replied. You also have to check IsWindowVisible. Now I got a list of the applications and their process IDs but I'm actually not sure how to get their names without getting a snapshot but that's a bit more code than I would think was necessary...

Comment: I must downvote, because as pointed  g-makulik what is definition of application?

Comment: I specifically said "list of applications like the windows task manager." But you didn't read anything but the title did you? What else am I suppose to call the things titled "applications" in the task manager?!

Comment: There's no such thing as "the application name". Task Manager will show the window caption instead. But e.g. Explorer.EXE uses that for folder names